Multiple citations of the same co-authors with individual page numbers using apacite
I'm using the apacite package. I want to cite two papers by the same co-authors in a single parenthetical citation, with separate page numbers and footnote numbers of each paper.
My current code is:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

(\citeNP[p. 9, footnote 26]{malink2016logic}; \citeNP[p. 152, endnote 1]{malink2017leibniz}).

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}

This results in:

(Malink and Vasudevan 2016, p. 9, footnote 26; Malink and Vasudevan 2017, p. 152, endnote 1).

What I want to appear is:

(Malink and Vasudevan 2016, p. 9, footnote 26; 2017, p. 152, endnote 1)


A friend of mine provided the following answer, which proved effective:
"A simple way is to use \citeNP for the first reference (which prints authors + year), and then use \citeyearNP for the second reference (which prints year only). For example: (\citeNP[p.~9, footnote~26]{malink2016logic}; \citeyearNP{malink2017leibniz}, p.~152, endnote~1) will give you: (Malink and Vasudevan, 2016, p. 9, footnote 26; 2017, p. 152, endnote 1)."
I'm posting it here in case anyone who has the same question sees this in the future.

Hi there, welcome to TeX StackExchange! If you answered your own question, instead of leaving a comment, you should post your answer using the answer box below.

It's also best to ensure your question and answer are self-contained. So, your question should include example code of a complete document showing your problem, and your answer should include working example code for the solution. Feel free to click the Edit button to edit your question!
